# MainActivity.java all grayed out

Tags: java, android

I added splash.xml and did project - clean which led to losing R.java. The cause was I have an mp3 file in raw folder which was giving error. I deleted that mp3 file and got back the R.java. Now my MainActivity.java is all grayed out. It's like none of the import or the code linked to activity_main.xml. All looks like something I have typed on notepad. Can someone point out what's wrong here?

```
package com.tenz.secondApp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Yout total is " + counter);
        }
    });

   sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is  " + counter);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>    android:orientation="vertical"
>    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
> ```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your total is 0" 
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Add one"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Add one"
    android:text="Subtract one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/bSub" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your activity_main layout file?

Comment: Where is this happening? Emulator, real device, ADT on eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: @user2199351 Check my code below. you've missed '>' to close linearlayout properly at the beginning in the activity_main.xml.

Comment: i have close, its just that it didn't showed up on here. sorry for that.. i edited it now .. my problem is with the MainActivity.java. usually your code comes out colored like import comes in pinkish and other blue but in MainActivity.java none is highlighted

Comment: if all is well at your end..it should come up fine as there is nothing big logic you've implemented here. Did u do project-->clean ? sometimes, it helps...closing the eclipse and restarting it again and check pls

Comment: i did project - clean several times and also close the eclipse several times.

Comment: funny thing is, when run it .. it just run perfectly ... weird !!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have multiple packages in your application.Please see your gen folder to verify that R.java in which package.and then
import packagename.R

Comment: in gen folder i have Buildconfig.java and R.java                                 (attr,dimen,drawable,id,layout,menu,string and style)

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your imports.

Just import R.java from your project

```
import <YourPkgName>.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed LinearLayout at the beginning properly hence the error. Use the below code. I tested by removing that error, it works perfectly fine..check this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your total is 0" 
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Add one"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Add one"
    android:text="Subtract one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/bSub" />

</LinearLayout>
```